# I need to show a msgbox saying "Please select a maximum of 8 data." when the user selected more than 8 cells in the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

So the maximum allowable data to be copied in another worksheet is 8. Everytime the user chooses more than 8 data, an error will occur. How can I show a my own msgbox instead of the default msgbox provided by VBA.

I am completely new to VBA.

This is my code. It works but I think it is applicable to all errors the user might encounter.

```
Sub CopySelectedCells()

    On Error GoTo EncounteredError

        Worksheets("3inch_OD7133KS ").Activate
        Selection.Resize(, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Form").Range("b7")
        Selection.Resize(, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Form").Range("b27")
        Selection.Resize(, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Form").Range("b47")

    Exit Sub

EncounteredError:

    MsgBox "ERROR OCCURED: Please choose a MAXIMUM of 8 data."


End Sub
```

Comment: May explore `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and use `Target.Cells.Count` to determine how may cells are selected. (But use the event only when you are well conversant with the effect of the event every time it fires)

Comment: Can you share your code please - right now we can only give you generic solutions which always end up with follow up questions/requested edits which can be avoided by simply sharing your code

Comment: Please add the code to your question - I’ll take a look after you get it done :)

Comment: Hi @urdearboy. I already edited the post and added my code. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: Should the selection be 8 rows? 8 columns? What is the size of the selection that you need? 8X1?

Comment: @urdearboy, the size is 8x1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`On Error GoTo Handler` is typically considered bad practice. You should always try to code out anticipated errors when possible for greater reliability. In this instance, we can simply check the size of the **.Selection** before taking any actions using `.Rows.Count` and `.Columns.Count`. We need to limit the sub to only work when this returns a `8 x 1` range.

---

*If this is all your sub is doing then this should be fine....*

```
Sub Selections()

If Selection.Rows.Count <> 8 Or Selection.Columns.Count <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Error Message Here"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Selection.Resize(, 4).Copy
        With Worksheets("3inch_OD7133KS ")
            .Range("B7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("B47").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
End If

End Sub
```

---

*If you have more code to add after you have validated the size of the selected range you can nest your test like this....*

```
Sub Selections()

If Selection.Rows.Count <> 8 Or Selection.Columns.Count <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Error Message Here"
    Exit Sub
End If

Selection.Resize(, 4).Copy
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("B7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("B27").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("B47").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

'More code here....

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much. @urdearboy Will be trying out the code.